# iOS - set a specific wifi connection as a portable hotspot

Tags: wifi, settings, data

If I use a portable hotspot or share Wi-Fi through another mobile device, is there a way to set that Wi-Fi connection as a data connection so that it won't try to upload stuff it only does on Wi-Fi like photos and updating apps and so on?

I ask because my other device with Android has this option and it has been life saving a couple of times.

Comment: It would be nice, but sadly apple doesn't seem to understand that people do have to use metered WiFi sometimes.  I had an iOS update download burn up an entire data allocation....

Comment: It appears this feature is still missing from iOS :( -- Feel free to submit a feature request at http://www.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 1):

To turn on Low Data mode in Wi-Fi follow the steps:

> **Wi-Fi**
>
> 1. Go to Settings and tap Wi-Fi
> 2. Tap the Info button next to
>    the Wi-Fi network that you're connected to.
> 3. Turn on Low Data
>    Mode.

From: [Use Low Data Mode on your iPhone and iPad](https://support.apple.com/HT210596)